# Strange convertion of pandas dataframe to spark dataframe with defined schema

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm facing the following problem and cound't get an answer yet: when converting a pandas dataframe with integers to a pyspark dataframe with a schema that supposes data comes as a string, the values change to "strange" strings, just like the example below. I've saved a lot of important data like that, and I wonder why that happened and if it is possible to "decode" these symbols back to integer forms. Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd 
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField,StringType

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"a": [111,222, 333]})

schema = StructType([
    StructField("a", StringType(), True)
])

sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
sparkdf.show()
```

Output:

```
--+
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  o|
|  Þ|
|  ō|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem on any recent version but the most likely reason is that you incorrectly defined the schema (in combination with enabled Arrow support).

Either cast the input:

```
df["a"] = df.a.astype("str")
```

or define the correct schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("a", LongType(), True)
])
```